# @material-ui icons not displaying on the screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to make a sidebar component and import the different icons to make the UI, but they aren't rendering on the screen. I tried other solutions mentioned here, didn't quite work.

```
<SidebarOption Icon = {InsertCommentIcon} title ="Threads"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {InboxIcon} title ="Mentions & Reactions"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {DraftsIcon} title ="Saved items"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {BookmarkBorderIcon} title ="Channel browser"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {PeopleAltIcon} title ="People & user groups"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {AppsIcon} title ="Apps"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {FileCopyIcon} title ="File browser"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {ExpandLessIcon} title ="Show less"/>
<SidebarOption Icon = {ExpandMoreIcon} title ="Show more"/>
```

**did the import as usual**

```
import InsertCommentIcon from "@material-ui/icons/InsertComment";
import DraftsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Drafts";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Inbox";
```

and so forth for all icons.

But the icons aren't visible on the sidebar. What do you think might be the issue and what should I fix?

Comment: Can you show me the `SidebarOption` definition?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8kB2vWyz 

here is it . pls have a look

Comment: nvm, it worked , just had to remove display:flex in the sidebar . Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

your imports are wrong, try these

```
import InsertCommentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/InsertComment';
import DraftsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Drafts';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Inbox';
```

and so on ...

also jsut to be sure, make sure that you installed MUI and Icons correclty:

```
npm install @mui/material
```

and

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Comment: The import path is right, just because they're using v4 doesn't mean the code stop working.

Comment: import is working fine.  as i am playing around with my code, I see the problem is that the icons are being displayed outside of the sidebar component .